# Why would you address a struct field by reference when you can do it by value?

Tags: c

Sorry for the title, I might have explained myself wrong there.

What I mean is that I saw somewhere in the code this piece `&struct_var->struct_field`.
My question is: why would you do that? If I understand everything correctly, in this case `struct_var` is not a pointer hence `struct_field` can be accessed simply by doing `struct_var.struct_field`. Is there any benefit to doing that or is there actually no difference at all and it might be a some sort of rudimentary way of doing it tailing from previous versions of whatever code I was looking at?

Comment: Because the *address* of the member is needed? For example by `scanf()` or other function that needs to modifiy it.

Comment: as you seem to have a basic misunderstanding about references vs pointers, it is essential that you are precise about the code. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: *"in this case struct_var is not a pointer"* - Unlikely given the use of  `->`. You misparsed the expression.

Comment: `&struct_var->struct_field` is not `(&struct_var)->struct_field`, it's `&(struct_var->struct_field)`

Comment: `&struct_var->struct_field` isn't accessing by reference, it's taking the address of `struct_field` (e.g. getting a **pointer**). As for why you would need that: Why not? If an API requires a pointer (or even a reference), then you must give that API what it asks for or it's a type error, since C++ is a strongly-typed language

Comment: Note that there is a *big* difference between C and C++ here. You mention *references*, but C doesn't have it while C++ does. So please pick *one* language, and please use the correct terminology.

Comment: Yes, here is the meaning of the whole line of code: SOME_PTR_TYPE *ptr = &struct_var->struct_field. It might be that we need to save an address of struct_var.struct_field into the pointer. But I just assumed that struct_field is already a pointer itself and '&' is related to struct_var.

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, I think you're right, thank you

Comment: don't "assume" that it is a pointer. Look at how `struct_var` is declared, and if you don't understand it show us the declaration so we can explain

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818, I unfortunately don't have a declaration of a struct in question. But yes I could have sorted this question out on my own if I looked closer, but for some reason I was certain in what I assumed, so I guess that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I looked it up and reference in C++ is not the same as what operator & does in C, I made that mistake because english is not my native language but I still thought that in english it also has the same name. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

`&struct_var->struct_field` takes the address of the member `struct_field` in a struct that's pointed to by `struct_var`. It's `&(struct_var->struct_field)`, not `(&struct_var)->struct_field`.

You'd use that when ever you have a valid need to modify a field of the struct through a pointer. A made-up example which should print `444`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo {
    int a;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct foo *s;
    s = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    s->a = 123;
    int *p = &s->a;
    (*p) += 321;
    printf("%d\n", s->a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I got this memorized well now